# dynamically inserted hidden text fields using .html() under form not passing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I dynamically inserted some hidden fields in between my form using .html() / .append() But when i i'm click the submit button the form not carrying the form details to my php page.

HTML:

```
<form action='/passenger.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div class='nebookclone'></div>
    <div class='twobookclone'></div>
    <table class='bus' id='onebus' cellspacing='0' align='left' cellpadding='5' width='50%'></table>
    <table class='bus' id='rebus' cellspacing='0' align='right' cellpadding='5' width='50%'></table>
    <div style='display:none;'>
        <input type='submit' value='Proceed' id='onetwobook' name='hellhappens' />
    </div>
</form>
<div id='reT'>
    <input type='hidden' id='price' name='price[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='tot' name='tot[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='nos' name='nos[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='seat_no' name='seat_no[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='bearth' name='bearth[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='seat_price' name='seat_price[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='sl' name='sl[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='dp' name='dp[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='bp' name='bp[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='board' name='board[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='tt' name='tt[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='ta' name='ta[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='operator' name='operator[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='servicekey' name='servicekey[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='source' name='source[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='destination' name='destination[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='lay' name='layout[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='date' name='date[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='bus_type' name='bus_type[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='start' name='start[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='reach' name='reach[]' />
</div>
<div class='seats'>
    <p>
        <input class='twobookclone' type='submit' value='Continue booking' />
    </p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.twobookclone').append($('#reT').clone().children().removeAttr('id'));
$("#selection form div input").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Submit button generally submits form, if you want to submit hidden fields try putting them into the form.

Comment: @Coderanonymous have you checked my jquery code ?

Comment: Yes, i have checked i think it suggests that you don't proper usage of jquery attributes. Refer `http://api.jquery.com/clone/`

Comment: did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a silly mistake in my php page, I observed in NET tab in console the data is passing to my php page.

What i did there i only echoed `$_POST['hellhappens'];` that only showing there. Finally i did `var_dump($_POST)` its fine, My data is successfully passing.

Answer (score 2):

those hidden inputs must be inside form tags!

move `<div id='reT'>` in there and try again

like:

```
<form action='/passenger.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div class='nebookclone'></div>
    <div class='twobookclone'></div>
    <table class='bus' id='onebus' cellspacing='0' align='left' cellpadding='5' width='50%'></table>
    <table class='bus' id='rebus' cellspacing='0' align='right' cellpadding='5' width='50%'></table>
    <div style='display:none;'>
        <input type='submit' value='Proceed' id='onetwobook' name='hellhappens' />
    </div>

<div id='reT'>
    <input type='hidden' id='price' name='price[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='tot' name='tot[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='nos' name='nos[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='seat_no' name='seat_no[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='bearth' name='bearth[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='seat_price' name='seat_price[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='sl' name='sl[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='dp' name='dp[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='bp' name='bp[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='board' name='board[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='tt' name='tt[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='ta' name='ta[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='operator' name='operator[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='servicekey' name='servicekey[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='source' name='source[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='destination' name='destination[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='lay' name='layout[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='date' name='date[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='bus_type' name='bus_type[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='start' name='start[]' />
    <input type='hidden' id='reach' name='reach[]' />
</div>
<div class='seats'>
    <p>
        <input class='twobookclone' type='submit' value='Continue booking' />
    </p>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: I can't, I have to clone these fields twice for my application.

Comment: just copy every thing inside `<form>` tag, or you won't be able to send the additional parameters